# GNU Make - build only out-of-date file in directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Pretty new to GNU Make. This is a less complex example of something more general I have been trying to get to work.

I have many input files that have similar name format .txt, and I have a shell script that will take the input file and generate an output of the same name but with a different extension .wc. I have written the following Make file.

```
# name of dependencies
SRC = $(wildcard *.txt)

# get name of targets (substitute .wc for .txt)
TAR = $(SRC:.txt=.wc)

all: $(TAR)

%.wc: %.txt
    sh word_count.sh $<
```

This runs fine, and will generate all the .wc output files. However, if I modify one of the input(dependency) files, they are all rebuilt. So the question is; what is the best way to get GNU Make to only process the modified .txt files in the directory?

Comment: You simplified your question too much. I did use your  `Makefile` and it does behave like you want, not like you claim to observe. So after `make` (in a directory with 5 files `*.txt`) then `touch a.txt` a further `make` is correctly only processing `a.txt`. Better show your real `Makefile` and list the actual files you have.

Comment: Thanks for checking it Basile. It was my dumb fault - my shell script was outputting the .wc files to a different directory that Make was expecting. Still,   your assurance that the script was good helped me figure this. Thanks

Comment: Next time: if you haver a `make --version` 4.x, use `make --trace` for debugging. With a make 3, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x`

Comment: OK great. Thanks for letting me know